# Oracle APEX PDF Reporting

Tags: oracle-apex

I am getting error

> Failed to load PDF Document

after I have configured instance settings and generating pdf file as report in v 4.2 and 5

Comment: Check your listner configuration first

Comment: How to check listener configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure ORDS as "Print Server" in Oracle APEX Instance Settings:
[See Detail here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3804821?sr=inbox)